# How to get multiple row data into a row with multiple columns

Tags: mysql, pivot

I have a MySQL table like this:

```
User_Id  course_name     course_location   course_id
1        course name 1   location 1        1
1        course name 2   location 2        2
1        course name 3   location 1        3
2        course name 2   location 1        2
2        course name 4   location 4        4
```

How can I get data a result like this:

```
User_id  course 1       course2        course3        course4
1        yes-location1  yes-location2  yes-location1  NULL
2        NULL           yes-location1  NULL           yes-location4
```

Comment: Which version of MySQL are you using?  What you want is called a pivot, this answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table should show you what you are looking for.

Answer (score 9):

You must Pivot data using `GROUP BY` with `MAX` aggregate and use `CASE` to filter by `User_id`.

#### Query:

```
SELECT User_id
    , MAX(
        CASE WHEN course_id = 1 THEN course_location END
    ) as Course_1
    , MAX(CASE WHEN course_id = 2 THEN course_location END) as Course_2
    , MAX(CASE WHEN course_id = 3 THEN course_location END) as Course_3
    , MAX(CASE WHEN course_id = 4 THEN course_location END) as Course_4
FROM data
GROUP BY User_id;
```

Sample query in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1268c/7/0).

You can replace `course_location` by `CONCAT('YES-', course_location)` is the leading `YES` is indeed needed.

#### Output:

```
User_Id | Course_1      | Course_2      | Course_3      | Course_4
1       | location 1    | location 2    | location 1    | (null)
2       | (null)        | location 1    | (null)        | location 4
```

Comment: This is an old thread, but what is the performance in doing this, what if I had 15 CASE fields I wanted to inject, and what if there was say 100,00o results in the db, using this method, would it have serious performance issues?

Answer (score -1):

Table Creation:

```
CREATE TABLE VMRRTEST_DATA (
        ID INTEGER, 
        CATG VARCHAR(30 ), 
        PRICE INTEGER, 
        DATE TIMESTAMP
    )
```

Insertion:

```
INSERT INTO VMRRTEST_DATA VALUES(1,'CAR',1000,CURRENT TIMESTAMP);

INSERT INTO VMRRTEST_DATA VALUES(2,'CAR',2000,(CURRENT TIMESTAMP)- 10 MINUTE);

INSERT INTO VMRRTEST_DATA VALUES(3,'CAR',1000,CURRENT TIMESTAMP - 20 minute);


INSERT INTO VMRRTEST_DATA VALUES(4,'CAR',30000,CURRENT TIMESTAMP);

INSERT INTO VMRRTEST_DATA VALUES(5,'CAR',5000,(CURRENT TIMESTAMP)-20 minute);
```

Result set:

```
ID CATG PRICE DATE
 -- ---- ----- --------------------------
  1 CAR   1000 2018-10-09 22:17:59.907636

  4 CAR  30000 2018-10-09 22:18:32.58254

  2 CAR   2000 2018-10-09 22:30:30.875961

  3 CAR   1000 2018-10-09 22:20:43.80537

  5 CAR   5000 2018-10-09 22:21:14.787224
```

Expected Result set:

```
 RANK ID CATG PRICE DATE
 ---- -- ---- ----- --------------------------
    1  3 CAR   1000 2018-10-09 22:20:43.80537
    1  2 CAR   2000 2018-10-09 22:30:30.875961
    1  5 CAR   5000 2018-10-09 22:21:14.787224
    1  4 CAR  30000 2018-10-09 22:18:32.58254
```

Solution:

```
SELECT Rank,ID,CATG,PRICE,DATE FROM 
( 

SELECT
--ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY PRICE ASC) AS RW_NM,
RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY PRICE ORDER BY DATE DESC) AS Rank,

ID,CATG,
PRICE
,DATE 
FROM  
VMRRTEST_DATA 
--WHERE Rank 
GROUP BY ID,DATE,CATG,PRICE

HAVING COUNT(*)>0
ORDER BY PRICE,DATE DESC
)
WHERE Rank = 1
```

Comment: Sorry, but your answer doesn't answer the question.